# How to loop over and edit stream values (string)

Tags: java, java-stream

Given this string we want count word occurrence (term frquency)

```
String input="this a test of tests",
```

This will split our phrase into words

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(input.toLowerCase().split("\\s")).parallel();
```

How to edit a the stream values ,as follow : if a element of the stream ends with an "s" character then remove it.

Comment: use filter operation on your stream.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    String input="this a test of tests";
    Map<String, Long> map = Stream.of(input.toLowerCase().split("\\s")).parallel()
        .map(s -> s.replaceFirst("s$", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(map);
```

result:

```
{a=1, test=2, thi=1, of=1}
```